# Не удается выполнить запись в поток

Tags: java

Пишу оболочку для сервера Minecraft и столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Есть поток, в котором непосредственно запускается jar файл сервера. Вот код:

```
public class ServerThread extends Thread{


    volatile public Process proc;
    volatile public InputStream is;
    volatile public OutputStream os;

    volatile public InputStreamReader reader;
    volatile public OutputStreamWriter writer;

    volatile public BufferedReader breader;
    volatile public BufferedWriter bwriter;


    @Override
    public void run() {

        proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar minecraft_server.1.10.2.jar nogui");

        is = proc.getInputStream();
        os = proc.getOutputStream();


        reader = new InputStreamReader (is);
        breader = new BufferedReader (reader);

        writer = new OutputStreamWriter (os);
        bwriter = new BufferedWriter (writer);

        while (true) {  
            String str = "";
            if(breader.ready()){
                str = breader.readLine();
            }

            //
            // Some work with strings
            //

            if(str.contains ("[Server Shutdown Thread/INFO]: Stopping server")){
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("exiting");
        serverState.set(0);
    }

    synchronized public void sendCommand(String str){
        bwriter.write(str);
        bwriter.flush();
    }
}
```

Этот поток запускается из некоторого внешнего потока, откуда также вызывается функция sendCommand(""). Примерно так:

```
class Test{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ServerThread thr = new ServerThread();
        thr.start();
        thr.sendCommand("/stop"); //stop server. See minecraft server commands
    }
}
```

Однако после вызова sendCommand(); ничего не происходит, как будто запись в поток не произошла. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: попробуйте передать символ конца строки (`writeLine` вместо `write`, или `"/stop\n"`).

Comment: @zRrr Спасибо, действительно помогло.

Comment: @zRrr оформите, пожалуйста, ответом.